# sqlcmd error , Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'd '

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I trying to call a stored procedure:

```
sqlcmd -d jas_bis -Q "exec GenerateXmlCassettem"
```

And execution code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateXmlCassettem
AS
    DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @fileName = 'C:\JAS\xml\CassetteList.xml'
    SET @sqlStr = 'select DevId as IdAutomate, id as idCassette, MedicineCode 
                   from jas_bis.dbo.Cassette 
                   where MedicineCode is not null for xml path'

SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

Here you can find db table: Cassette that I use to excute stored procedure:

```
SELECT TOP (1000)
    [DevID], [Id],
    [Drawer], [Row], [Column],
    [Side], [DropDelay],
    [MedicineCode], [Priority],
    [RemainQty], [Unit],
    [Type], [MinQty], [ExpDT], [UseExpDT],
    [LotNO], [Barcode]
FROM 
    [jas_bis].[dbo].[Cassette]
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'D:'.

Comment: Did you try `PRINT @sqlCmd;` instead of `EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd` so you know what you are even trying to execute?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't quote your query into your bcp call. So the call results into

```
bcp select DevId as IdAutomate, id as idCassette,MedicineCode 
from jas_bis.dbo.Cassette where MedicineCode is not null for xml path queryout C:\JAS\xml\CassetteList.xml -w -T
```

It should be

```
bcp "select DevId as IdAutomate, id as idCassette,MedicineCode 
from jas_bis.dbo.Cassette where MedicineCode is not null for xml path" queryout C:\JAS\xml\CassetteList.xml -w -T
```

And quoting the filename would also be better

Comment: i could't excute with your reforme can you send me all the query please

Comment: You fixed this part as I expected. Do you still have the same error ? Because stg bothers me : I don't see any parameter related to the server/database you want to reach with bcp. As @Aaron Bertrand said, first get the content of ```@sqlStr``` and run it from a DOS prompt